# Como bloqueio <tr> depois de clicar uma vez

Tags: javascript, ajax

Eu tenho varias linha da tabela e quando click em uma `<tr>` roda esse script:

```
 $(function(){
            $('tr').click(function(){
            $("tr").prop("disabled", true);
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            $.post("shopweb_item.php",{id: id}, function(data){
              $('#resultado').html(data);
              $("#comprar").prop("disabled", false);
            });
          });
        });
```

Só que mesmo eu utilizando:

```
$("tr").prop("disabled", true);
```

Se o usuário click mais de uma vez a requisição e repetida então o retorno do `shopweb_item.php` é um modal e acaba abrindo mais de uma vez é depois que eu fecho ainda fica a pagina mais escura e impossibilita de click, alguém tem alguma ideia?

Eu tirei o `$("tr").prop("disabled", true);` desse outro script:

```
  // evento de "submit"
        $("#comprar").click(function (event) {
            // parar o envio para que possamos faze-lo manualmente.
            event.preventDefault();
            // capture o formulário
            var form = $('#formulario')[0];
            // crie um FormData {Object}
            var data = new FormData(form);
            // caso queira adicionar um campo extra ao FormData
            // data.append("customfield", "Este é um campo extra para teste");
            // desabilitar o botão de "submit" para evitar multiplos envios até receber uma resposta
            $("#comprar").prop("disabled", true);
            // processar
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                url: "enviar.php",
                data: data,
                processData: false, // impedir que o jQuery tranforma a "data" em querystring
                contentType: false, // desabilitar o cabeçalho "Content-Type"
                cache: false, // desabilitar o "cache"
                timeout: 600000, // definir um tempo limite (opcional)
                // manipular o sucesso da requisição
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    $("#msg").html(data);
                    // reativar o botão de "submit"
                    //limpar form
                      $('#formulario').each (function(){
                          this.reset();
                        });
                    $("#comprar").prop("disabled", false);
                },
                // manipular erros da requisição
                error: function (e) {
                    console.log(e);
                    // reativar o botão de "submit"
                    $("#comprar").prop("disabled", false);
                }
            });
        });
```

Porem pego os dados de um `<from>` não sei pegar o id do `<tr>` com esse segundo script.

HTML:

```
<tr id="<?php echo $shopweb->id_shop; ?> ">
 <td><img src="<?php echo "$shopweb->icone"; ?>"></td>
 <td><?php echo "$shopweb->nome"; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo "$shopweb->categoria_s"; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo "$shopweb->tipo_s"; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo "$shopweb->level"; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo "$shopweb->preco"; ?></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A propriedade `disabled` não tem nenhum efeito em `tr.`

O que você pode fazer é desativar o evento `click` quando clicar na `tr`.

Por exemplo:

```
$("tr").click(function(event) {
    alert("Clicado!");
    $(this).off("click");
});
```

Veja funcionando [aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/w77r8L36/).

Comment: Não funcionou continua do mesmo jeito.

Comment: @Everton Figueiredo Alterou a linha $("tr").prop("disabled", true)? Qual versão do seu jquery? Consegue colocar o pedaço do html que é feito o click?

Comment: Sim vou editar.

Comment: @EvertonFigueiredo Onde está o elemento com o id #comprar?

Comment: Esta em um modal que se abre, sua resposta ajudou muito consegui assim.